# Appending <h2> tags and <p> <strong> in Web scraper

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Background:**
I am trying to scrape a recipe website, for each recipe's 'Method'. I am running into difficult changing some code I created to fit my exacting specifications:

**Current Code (1):**

```
from scraper_api import ScraperAPIClient
from splinter import Browser
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

executable_path = {'executable_path': ChromeDriverManager().install()}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)

resp = requests.get("https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cooking_for_two_strawberry_almond_oat_smoothie/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser")
div = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "sr-recipe-method"})

# select all <p> tag's inside the <div>
for p in div.findAll("p"):
    # check if <strong> exist's inside <p> tag
    if p.find('strong'):
        print(p.text)
```

**Current output (1):**

```
1 Combine the ingredients: In a blender, combine the oats, strawberries, yogurt, almond milk, banana, and almond extract.
2 Puree the smoothie: Starting on low speed, puree the ingredients. Turn the blender on high and continue to puree until smooth. Serve right away.
```

**Desired output**
Whilst this code returns the method / steps, I would like to evolve the code so:

1. the recipe title is the key
2. the method (which are contained within `<strong>` `<p>` tags and this recipe has 2x methods) is the value, comma separated
3. The output is stored in the structure shown in the 'Desired output'

`{Strawberry Almond Oat Smoothie Recipe': [1 Combine the ingredients: In a blender, combine the oats, strawberries, yogurt, almond milk, banana, and almond extract, 2 Puree the smoothie: Starting on low speed, puree the ingredients. Turn the blender on high and continue to puree until smooth. Serve right away.]}`

**Revised code attempt:**

```
div = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "sr-recipe-callout"})
method = {" ".join(div.find("h2").text.split()):
           [x.text for x in p.findAll("p", attrs={"class": "entry-details recipe-method instructions"})]}
```

**Revised code output:**

```
{'Strawberry Almond Oat Smoothie Recipe': []}
```

HTML for web page
[image]

Any suggestions on how I can revise my code to give the Desired Output would be greatly received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cooking_for_two_strawberry_almond_oat_smoothie/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

out, current = {}, ''
for tag in soup.select('.recipe-callout h2, .recipe-callout p:has(strong)'):
    if tag.name == 'h2':
        current = tag.text
        out[current] = []
    else:
        out[current].append(tag.text)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width = 120)
```

Prints:

```
{'Strawberry Almond Oat Smoothie Recipe': ['1 Combine the ingredients: In a blender, combine the oats, strawberries, '
                                           'yogurt, almond milk, banana, and almond extract.',
                                           '2 Puree the smoothie: Starting on low speed, puree the ingredients. Turn '
                                           'the blender on high and continue to puree until smooth. Serve right away.']}
```

Comment: Hi Andrej - thank you for responding. When I run this code, I seem to get a 'AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'select''

Comment: @William Do you run **exactly** the same code? Running the code above gives me the desired result. On what are you calling the `.select`? On `soup` object? What type is the `soup` object? Try to `print(type(soup))`

Comment: Turns out the website blocked me! I just implemented import scraper_API from ScraperAPIClient and it worked. Thank you! If you have the opportunity to explain the code, I'd be most grateful, just so I can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reach the url you provided but here is an example with [that one](https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/mozzarella_and_basil_stuffed_tomatoes/).
Personally, I prefer using `lxml` to process html documents. Here is how I would do it:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

def get_recipe(url):
    res = requests.get(url=url, timeout=5)
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(res.text)
    recipe = root.find_class('recipe-description')[0]
    ol = recipe.xpath('.//ol')[0]
    lis = ol.xpath('.//li')
    title = root.find_class('entry-title')[0].text_content().strip()
    return {title: [_.text_content().strip() for _ in lis]}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = get_recipe("https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/mozzarella_and_basil_stuffed_tomatoes/")
    print(test)
    # {
    #     'Mozzarella and Basil Stuffed Tomatoes': [
    #         'Remove the vines and stems. Wash the tomatoes, but do not core them.',
    #         'Next, slice the tomatoes in half horizontally and use a spoon to scoop out the flesh. Because of the uniformly round shape of the tomatoes on the vine, each half will easily sit up on its own. If you accidentally puncture a hole in the bottom, no worries! The filling will close it up.',
    #         'Lastly, prepare the filling. Instead of discarding the inside of the tomato, drain off the seeds and water, then chop what remains up to be used in the filling. If you notice the core or the flesh near the stem end is particularly tough, don’t include it.']
    #  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code Niko - I'm not familiar with lxml.html, but I'll certainly use this as a learning opportunity